# JAX-WS @DefaultValue annotation is being ignored

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jax-ws

I am using Spring MCV and if I annotate my controller method with the DefaultValue annotation I am getting a serialization error

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page", method = RequestMethod.GET)
page(@DefaultValue("10") @QueryParam("pageSize") int pageSize
```

Returns the following error if I don't pass the pageSize parameter to the controller:

> Optional int parameter 'pageSize' is present but cannot be translated
>   into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider
>   declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.

Am I misusing DefaultValue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two implemetation, Spring and JAX-RS, if you are using Spring then you can have code like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String page(@RequestParam(name = "pageSize", defaultValue = "10") int pageSize) {

}
```